# Is $M$ the midpoint of this line?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

$${{\bullet\!\!\! -\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\bullet\!\!\! -\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\bullet}\atop O \;\quad\quad M\quad\quad\; P}$$

Given that $OM = x + 8$, $MP = 2x - 6$, $OP = 44$, is $M$ the midpoint of $OP$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** $$OM + MP = OP$$
Move your mouse over the gray area for the complete solution.

> Note that $$OM + MP = OP$$ and hence we get that $3x+2 = 44 \implies x =14$. Hence, $OM = 14 + 8 = 22 = \dfrac{44}2 = \dfrac{OP}2$. Hence, $M$ is indeed the midpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my only question is how did you find out that OM + MP = OP?

Comment: @Michael Since $M$ is a point on the line, we have the distance from $O$ to $P$ is nothing but the sum of the distance from $O$ to $M$ and then from $M$ to $P$.

Comment: Ah okay. So for my other problem where: PQ = x^2 +3 and QR = 4+2x and PR = 15 then it is safe to say that PQ + QR = 15? and in this case how would you proceed?

Comment: If $PQR$ are along a line and $Q$ is inbetween $P$ and $R$, then $PQ + QR = PR$. If this is the case, then we get that $$x^2 + 3 + 4 + 2x = 15 \implies x^2 + 2x -8 = 0$$ Now can you find $x$, keeping in mind that $QR \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes. So that means that x^2+x = 4. So x = 2?

Comment: @Michael $x^2 + 2x = 8 \, \& \, 2x+4 \geq 0 \implies x=2$

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$OM + MP = OP$$
so
$$(x+8)+(2x-6)=3x+2=44$$
$$3x=42$$
$$x=14$$
Therefore $OM=x+8=22$ and $MP=2\cdot 14-6=28-6=22$. Because the lengths of $OM$ and $MP$ are equal, $M$ is the midpoint of the line $OP$.